# sklearn.linear_model LogisticRegression selecting columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I've imported the `LogisticRegression` model from `sklearn`. My dataset has 785 columns, of which the first column is the label which I'm trying to train to predict.

This is my code.

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf = clf.fit(train[[1:785]], train['label'])
```

I get the following error,

```
File "<ipython-input-22-1c2c333722ad>", line 2
    clf = clf.fit(train[[1:785]], train['label'])
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I select all columns except the first one without explicitly mentioning all the column names.

Comment: Print out `train.__class__`, please.

Comment: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Comment: `clf = clf.fit(train.ix[:, 1:], train['label'])`. This will select every column except the first one.

Comment: @E.Z. Note that from 0.20 upwards, [ix is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated). Recommended is `iloc` and `loc`.

Comment: The double square brackets `[[` in pandas Dataframe dont accept slices as index. They accept a list of column or column indices. In addition to @E.Z. 's comment, you can also use `clf = clf.fit(train[[i for i in range(785)]], train['label'])`.

Comment: You could also: `train[[train.columns[1:]]` to leave the first column out.

Comment: In my previous comment, the solution suggested will take all columns i.e from 0. Correct usage is `clf = clf.fit(train[[i for i in range(1, 785)]], train['label'])` .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
clf = clf.fit(train.iloc[:,1:], train[['label']])
```